# Getting "undefined reference to"-Error after "go install" when using SWIG

Tags: c++, go, swig

I am having problems when trying to use SWIG to access C++-code from my GO-code.

My simplistic setup is:

Simple.h:

```
#include <iostream>

class SimpleSwig
{
    public:
        void hello_world();
};
```

Simple.cpp:

```
#include "Simple.h"

void hello_world()
{
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
}
```

simple.i:

```
%module simple

%{
#include "Simple.h"
%}

%include Simple.h
```

main.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "ctogoswig/swig"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("go ...")

    s := simple.NewSimpleSwig()
    s.Hello_world()

    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

Issuing

```
$ swig -go -c++ -intgosize 64 .\simple.swigcxx
```

gives me the new files simple.go and simple_wrap.cxx.

When I then issue

```
$ go install
```

I am getting:

[image]

A call to

```
$ go build -x
```

yields:

[image]

My Go environment variables are:

[image]

So, what am I missing?

The mentioned line 277 in the "undefined reference" exception is within the file simple_wrap.cxx:

[image]

Maybe also relevant is that within this file the following include is present a little before line 277:

[image]

Comment: You have an undefined reference to `SimpleSwig::hello_world()`. Could you please point out where that is defined? (Not `hello_world()`, but `SimpleSwig::hello_world()`.)

Comment: @JaMiT... of course, please see my update.

Comment: That's where you're using the symbol not where it's defined. You've delcared the method `SimpleSwig::hello_world()` but you have defined the global function `hello_world()` not `SimpleSwig::hello_world()`

Comment: @AlanBirtles believe it or not, but you nailed it - you gave me the right answer! My dear, unknown friend - you ended days of suffering for me! Thank YOU!

Comment: To avoid future suffering if you dont understand an error message then copy and paste it into google and you'll undoubtedly find a SO post where someone else has encountered the same error